# "You will find taxis waiting at the bus station ______ you can hire to reach your host family"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> You will find taxis waiting at the bus station **__** you can hire to reach your host family

Two options:

> 1. which
> 2. where

Which one is correct?
I think (2), but the answer is (1): why is that?

Comment: "*where you can hire to reach your host family*" is not well-formed.

Comment: There is also the option of Zero. _taxis waiting at the bus station ∅ you can hire to reach your host family_ is also correct.

Answer (score 5):

*You can hire* requires an object, beause *you can hire to reach your family* is not grammatical without one; *hire* is not an intransitive verb.

The sentence already mentions the taxis at the bus station, so you need to refer to those. The way to do that is with *which*.

> **which** *pronoun & determiner*
> used referring to something previously mentioned when introducing a clause giving further information
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/which?q=which)
>
> ---
>
> You will find taxis waiting at the bus station which you can hire to reach your family.

*Where* is principally concerned with **place** (either literal or metaphorical). If you used *where*, it would refer to the bus station and you would still have the above ungrammatical fragment. You would need to add an object explicitly, such as *them*:

> You will find taxis waiting at the bus station where you can hire them to reach your host family.

That sentence is awkward. You don’t need to use *where* to specify the location because it’s understood from the context. The sentence can only apply to the bus station. It’s also not an option for you because you can’t add the word *them*.

Note that *which* **could** refer to either of the preceding nouns: the taxis or the bus station. Context makes clear which is meant. You can’t hire a bus station to reach your family, but a sentence like

> You will find taxis waiting at the bus station which is in the centre of town.

obviously refers to the bus station (because of the singular verb *is* which can’t refer to the plural *taxis*). Many would add a comma before *which* in that second sentence, as that also makes that meaning clear.

Comment: Yes - _You will find taxis waiting beside the rickshaws which you can hire to reach your host family_ is probably better re-ordered to _You will find taxis, which you can hire to reach your host family, waiting beside the rickshaws._

Comment: @Edwin not quite.  Why is the family waiting beside the rickshaws?  *Beside the rickshaws you will find taxis which you can hire to reach your host family* is the least ambiguous version.

Comment: _Waiting at the bus station_ comes from _which are waiting at the bus station_, a relative clause reduced by Whiz-deletion. _You can hire to reach your host family_ comes from _which you can hire in order to reach your host family_, also a relative clause, reduced this time by deletion of the relative pronoun. Both clauses modify _taxis_, so putting them together this way is awkward, but they can be ordered either way, and there's no relative pronoun necessary.

Comment: We could make _where_ okay with the addition of a single word: _You will find taxis waiting at the bus station, where you can hire **one** to reach your host family_. In that case, _where_ is correct, but _which_ would be incorrect. As you say, "you can hire" requires an object. Nice explanation.